# GLSL Uniforms initializing is allowed from GLSL version 1.20

Tags: opengl, glsl, intel

I get the following errors:

```
WARNING: uniforms initializing is allowed from GLSL version 1.20
WARNING: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
```

While I know how to fix that, I wonder why this could happen, as the machine this occured on has OpenGL 3.1 and so has GLSL 1.4:

```
12:40:58 [INFO] Intel(R) HD Graphics Family
12:40:58 [INFO] OpenGL 3.1.0 - Build 8.15.10.2509
```

EDIT:
The shader in question is a fragement shader (with no vertex shader):

```
uniform sampler2D sampler;
uniform sampler2D bump;

uniform float imageSize;
uniform float range = 50;

void main() {
    vec2 pos = gl_TexCoord[0].xy;

    float height = texture2D(bump, gl_TexCoord[0].xy).r - 0.5;

    pos.y += height * range / imageSize;

    gl_FragColor = texture2D(sampler, pos);

            //gl_FragColor = texture2D(sampler, pos) *  (1 + (height - 0.3f) * 25);
}
```

Comment: Did you specify a #version directive? You have to declare what version you want to use for each shader.

Comment: Always provide pertinent information in question. Like, in this case, the shader in question.

Comment: @Tim No, thanks for that, I'm trying that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The GLSL specification states that if the shader does not provide a [`#version` directive](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_Core_Language#Version), then it assumes version 1.10. Make sure to always provide a `#version` directive at the top of your shader.

Comment: Yeah, that was it. Seems like just Intel does interpret the specifications strictly, at least it ran with out #version and all Ati and Nvidea grafics cards before.